# Unable to access settings of the BOINC manager

Tags: lubuntu, boinc

Whenever I try to access the settings of the BOINC manager (version 7.9.3(x64)), all I get is a grey box. How do I make the actual settings appear? I run it on Lubuntu 18.4.2 LTS.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on a fresh 19.04 installation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't come up with a solution yet.

Comment: You can try to change computing settings in your web-profile, or in XML file - https://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/Prefs2