# BOINC Manager Compute Preferences blank

Tags: boinc

Running Ubuntu 22.10, Mate desktop environment. I installed boinc-client and boinc-manager via apt. All works fine in this pre-release version of BOINC (7.20.2+dfsg), except, when I open the Computing Preferences, I get a blank dialog box, with only the window controls in the title bar.

Searching here I found question 1134597 ([Unable to access settings of the BOINC manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134597/unable-to-access-settings-of-the-boinc-manager)), which seems to be the same issue from 2019, never answered.

For the time being I used cpulimit to force down CPU usage, but that's not a very polished or ideal way to handle this.

Suggestions?

Comment: Today it's mysteriously working.

I have no idea what changed.

Comment: When you say "settings" are you talking about the "Computing preferences" or another menu? Does this happen with any other software? I wonder if it is a driver/library issue. Does lowering the CPU usage fix this issue? I also wonder if you are better off with a Long Term Support Version (LTS) of Ubuntu; I use LTS 22.04 with Boinc 7.20.5 (x64) and all the preferences and option menus work.

Comment: It has been long enough now that it is irrelevant. Several versions of the client and a new OS later, it works as designed. I did mean Computing preferences.

Comment: OK, this is just bizarre. I set up a completely new system and ... computing preferences remains blank. I9 with nVidia GPU, might be useful to the project if they'd accept my help, darn it.

Comment: You can try to change computing settings in your web-profile (works for me), or in XML file - https://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/Prefs2

Answer (score 1):

As of this exact moment on Debian bookworm, I got the blank Computing Preferences dialog from the simple view of the BOINC Manager. If I switch to the Advanced View, the dialog displays normally.

That's one serious bug, but at least it's easy to work around once you know.

Comment: Not working for me - exception with app crash.